# Web-based open source screen sharing (voice, chat, control, file transfer)?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm looking for an open source screen sharing that is web-based, are there any good options that I can look into?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [BigBlueBUtton](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/) software. It is a free and opensource web conferencing software. there is no limit to share the number of webcams in a session.
- [OpenMeetings](https://openmeetings.apache.org/) is the another opensource, web-based software. It provides screen sharing facility as well. It has been downloaded over 250,000 times.
- Mconf is an open-source and free web conferencing system. It is an advanced and more customized version of BIgBlueButton. You can use this software too.